# JavaScript date calculation event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following code for a JavaScript calculation to calculate the different between two dates. I have the function on the `.change` event of one of the fields `conference_date_out`, however, if I go back and change the `date_in` date - the calculation in "total days" does not update.  What am I doing wrong?

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
        })({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
        $(".datepicker").datepicker;
    });
    $('#conference_date_out').change(function () {
        var start = $('#conference_date_in').datepicker('getDate');
        var end = $('#conference_date_out').datepicker('getDate');
        var days = (end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
        document.getElementById('total_days').value = days;
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<title>Conference Form</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="css/jqueryui.css"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqueryui.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/jqueryui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <table width="705" border="1" align="left" cellpadding="1">
            <form action="" method="get" name="myform">
                <tr>
                    <td width="151">
                        <label>Company Name</label>
                    </td>
                    <td width="158">
                        <input type="text" name="companyname" id="companyname" />
                    </td>
                    <td width="155">Enquiry Date</td>
                    <td width="213">
                        <input type="text" name="enquiry_date" id="enquiry_date" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Conference Date In</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="conference_date_in" id="conference_date_in" class="datepicker"
                        />
                    </td>
                    <td>Conference Date Out</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="conference_date_out" id="conference_date_out"
                        class="datepicker" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Number of Delegates</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="no_of_delegates" id="no_of_delegates" />
                    </td>
                    <td>Total Days</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="total_days" id="total_days" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </form>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are embedding css/jqueryui.css both as script and stylesheet.

Comment: Also, tables for layout is a very bad practice, we now have CSS for that. (Totally unrelated to the question though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only bound the update function to the 'out' field.  Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    })({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
    $(".datepicker").datepicker;
});

var calcDate = function() {
    var start = $('#conference_date_in').datepicker('getDate');
    var end = $('#conference_date_out').datepicker('getDate');
    var days = (end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;

    document.getElementById('total_days').value = days;
}

$('#conference_date_out').change(calcDate);
$('#conference_date_in').change(calcDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple: you bound the `change` handler only to `#conference_date_out` and not to `#conference_date_in`.

```
$('#conference_date_in').add('#conference_date_out').change(function() {
    var start = $('#conference_date_in').datepicker('getDate');
    var end = $('#conference_date_out').datepicker('getDate');
    var days = (end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
    document.getElementById('total_days').value = days;
});
```

Comment: thank you very much.  It is now working great.  Is there perhaps a way to prevent the user from selecting dates which are in the past? (and from selecting the _conference_date_in to be "after" the date_out?

Comment: Have a look at the [minDate](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-minDate) and [maxDate](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-maxDate) options on the jQuery UI Datepicker API page. In your `change` handler, you can set the `minDate` of `#conference_date_out` to the current value of `#conference_date_in` and the `maxDate` of `#conference_date_in` to the current value of `#conference_date_out`. I think you'll need to do a bit more work to make sure you can set them both on the same day by toying with the times of the dates.

Comment: thank you.  I have edited the code as follows: (however it is not working, is my syntax incorrect or placed in the wrong place?)  $('#conference_date_out').change(calcDate);
$('#conference_date_in').change(calcDate);({ minDate: -0, maxDate: "+12M +100D" });
</script>

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your jquery as follows:

1. add a shared class to your conference dates:

   `<input class="conference_date" name="conference_date_out"/>`

   `...`

   `<input class="conference_date" name="conference_date_out"/>`
2. then you can listen for changes to both using:

   **`$('.conference_date').change(function() { ...`**

   instead of:

   `$('#conference_date_in').add('#conference_date_out').change(function() {`

You save on javscript code and you can use the shared class for other listeners/styles.